# Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL Database as well as an Azure App Service.

I use an App Registration to connect the user via Active Directory, I get the error `Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'`. Actually, I get that error regardless, even if I don't log the user in.

Also, I can connect to the database via SSMS, but if I have another person in the organization connect, that same error shows up after I've added them as a user and given them the db_ddladmin, db_datawriter, and db_datareader roles.

There was a brief fleeting moment that I instead got a "The SELECT permission was denied..." error when running my web app, but it was seemingly random and now back to the token error.

Additionally, I've had a `DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token` error at one point, but I'm not sure what I did to "fix" it to the token error.

I HAVE gotten the web app to successfully connect. Specifically, if I set the authentication method to `Active Directory Interactive` and run it locally, it will work. However, I can't use that authentication method when running on the headless server (and it gives me a `HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component` error if I try).

The stack trace in C# is:

```
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnection.cs:line 776 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 1835 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 0 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 2355 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 1451 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, Boolean disableTnir) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 2320 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 1920 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 1727 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, ServerCertificateValidationCallback serverCallback, ClientCertificateRetrievalCallback clientCallback, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, SqlClientOriginalNetworkAddressInfo originalNetworkAddressInfo, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 554 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnectionFactory.cs:line 145 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionFactory.cs:line 148 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 910 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 2014 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 1419 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 1302 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionFactory.cs:line 339 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionInternal.cs:line 770 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:line 2130 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:line 2101 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:line 1658
```

The connection string is `Server=tcp:the-name-of-the-server.database.usgovcloudapi.net,1433;Initial Catalog=TheDatabaseName;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=\"Active Directory Default\";`
However, I have tried pretty much every Authentication method.
The fact that my coworker can't connect either is indicative of a problem unrelated to the web app itself but rather with the Azure SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Identity ChainedTokenCredential need to set properly - Visual Studio token may not be the priority, Keep the Azure Credential as top priority..

Answer (score -1):

Check this documentation on how to connect to Azure DB from App Service:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-azure-database?tabs=sqldatabase%2Csystemassigned%2Cnetfx%2Cwindowsclient